# How to set default value in select box in Vue.js?

Tags: html, vue.js

This may be trivial but I could not make a select box in Vue.js template to show `US` as default (that is before the drop down being clicked)

```
<select v-model="country">                                           
    <option selected="selected">US</option>
    <option>UK</option>
    <option>EU</option>
</select>
```

The problem is that selector appears blank before being clicked whatever I try.

How can I fix it?

Comment: What is wrong? What is not going well? What is the problem?

Comment: The selector appears blank before being clicked.

Comment: I made a file that has the same structure as yours, and it appears selected for me.

Comment: Please notice, I'm taliking about `vue.js` template not ordinary html.

Comment: OK, will test with Vue. What's the URL of the file you're using?

Comment: There is no url. I'm testing locally.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179608/discussion-between-jbdouble05-and-babr).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [Form Input Bindings - Select](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select). You just need to set your bound `v-model` property to the appropriate value.

Here's an example...

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    country: 'US'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="country">
    <!-- as recommended by Vue -->
    <option disabled value="">Please select one</option>
    <option>US</option>
    <option>UK</option>
    <option>EU</option>
  </select>
  
  <pre>Selected country: {{ country }}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: I had tried that. Still `US` does not appear on the selector bar.

Comment: @Babr can you add your JavaScript code to your question? How and where do you assign a value to `country`?

Comment: Sorry Phil, stupid me! I had put `country` outside `data`! Thanks for the tip.